# Vuetify grid positioning

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm coding an online store page with vuetify. I'm loading from firestore a collection of products and then I create columns and rows to display 3 products cards per row.
I come from a bootstrap background and even if I have searched a solution for this problem and I have read the vuetify documentation I'm still really struggling with this problem:

I want that every row is filled by 3 columns (lg="3") cause I want margins left and right. I have managed to doing this with this code:

```
<v-row v-for="chunk in productChunks" :key="chunk" class="justify-center">
  <v-col cols="12" lg="3" md="12">
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

However in this way if I have for example 4 products, the 4th one is centered and not placed in the left of the row (of course due to the justify center).

So my question is: how can I make a row centered without using the justify center prop?

Comment: Just don't use justify-center.

Comment: Yes but if I don't use justify center, the whole rows content shifts to the left cause I will have 3/12 of space free to the right in every row

Comment: Seems like what you want is centering the grid itself and not the content. As @AdamOrlov suggested remove justify-center and center the v-row in its parent.